# Running NUnit tests on Travis for dot net core 2.0 fails - System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException

Tags: nunit, .net-core, travis-ci

I have just started to use **Travis CI** to build a project on git hub but am struggling to get NUnit tests to run successfully. I am experiencing a `System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.`.

My `run-test.sh` looks like:

```
nunit-console Code/Shared/ORMS.Shared.SharedKernel.UnitTests/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.0/ORMS.Shared.SharedKernel.UnitTests.dll
```

which should be the correct path to my test project. My `.travis.yml` looks like:

```
language: csharp
dist: trusty
sudo: required
mono: none
dotnet: 2.0.0
solution: OpenRMS.sln
branches:
  only:
    - master-net-core
before_install:
  - sudo apt-get install nunit-console
before_script:
  - chmod +x build.sh
  - chmod +x run-tests.sh
script:
  - ./build.sh
  - ./run-tests.sh
```

which should be loading the NUnit test runner which it appears to do from [the output](https://travis-ci.org/dibley1973/OpenRMS/builds/276699427) but there is another dependency load issue, which I cannot get to the bottom of.

Failed output:

```
$ ./run-tests.sh
NUnit-Console version 2.6.0.0
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.
Runtime Environment - 
   OS Version: Unix 4.4.0.93
  CLR Version: 4.0.30319.17020 ( Mono 4.0 ( 3.2.8 (Debian 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1.1) ) )
ProcessModel: Default    DomainUsage: Single
Execution Runtime: mono-4.0
Unhandled Exception:
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
Server stack trace: 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly:GetTypes (System.Reflection.Assembly,bool)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExportedTypes () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NUnit.Core.CoreExtensions.InstallAdhocExtensions (System.Reflection.Assembly assembly) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Load (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build (System.String assemblyName, Boolean autoSuites) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build (System.String assemblyName, System.String testName, Boolean autoSuites) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.BuildSingleAssembly (NUnit.Core.TestPackage package) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.Build (NUnit.Core.TestPackage package) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NUnit.Core.SimpleTestRunner.Load (NUnit.Core.TestPackage package) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load (NUnit.Core.TestPackage package) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load (NUnit.Core.TestPackage package) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at NUnit.Core.RemoteTestRunner.Load (NUnit.Core.TestPackage package) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper xdomain-dispatch) NUnit.Core.RemoteTestRunner:Load (object,byte[]&,byte[]&)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
  at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) NUnit.Core.RemoteTestRunner:Load (NUnit.Core.TestPackage)
  at NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load (NUnit.Core.TestPackage package) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
The command "./run-tests.sh" exited with 156.
```

I think the key line is...

```
at NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load (NUnit.Core.TestPackage package) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

... so it looks as if it is loading an unknown file?

Any suggestions how to narrow this down. I am very new to Travis and normally use MSTest at work, but want to use NUnit as it has some features which I believe MSTest is yet to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to run .NET Core unit tests from a mono-based version of the NUnit console runner, which does not support .NET Core dlls (see [GitHub issue](https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/271)).

To run tests, use `dotnet test` on the test project or `dotnet vstest` on the publish output created by running `dotnet publish` on the test project.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that at home tonight. I did originally try `dotnet test` but  that seemed to have other issues which is why I changed track.

Comment: I've created a PR on your GitHub project to see if it works

Comment: The PR just built fine and ran the tests

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you. I have just accepted your PR. Thanks again for taking the time to fix my issue.